# Offensive comments - How to deal with these

Tags: discussion, comments, offensive

I marked an answer "as not providing an answer to the question" and I received a series of insults from the answerer. How to deal with these type of situations? I think that people not willing to be criticized and acting offensively should be banned for a while. Which countermeasures are taken in situations like this?
Moreover, if the OP indicate that he has thousand of points while showing only 35 points, can this be understood like he has double account on SO?

Comment: Flag them as offensive...

Comment: Just a note, there's no point you (or anyone else) exacerbating this further by engaging... Just leave well alone. And, I've been alive since 1984, and using a computer since 1989, so I know this.

Comment: @Ben, I agree with you. I limited my self in explaining why I marked the answer in that way then I left him alone.

Comment: More comments to flag it seems.

Comment: @Mysticial A question; is it high-rep users that deal with offensive flags, an auto-system, or diamond mods? ... Or some combination of any of the prior three?  Aside, I'm beginning to run out of flags.

Comment: @Daedalus Only mods can see comment flags. But under some circumstances, a comment can be deleted via flags without moderator intervention.

Comment: @Mysticial Alright then; thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Ben: oh, you young, young fry. I've been alive since 1973 and been *chasing babies like you of my lawn [since 1984](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/15464/Toshiba-MSX-HX-10/)!*

Comment:  @Martijn. It was meant to be a riff off the '96 comment, just earlier and with things people could still turn into a competition but were less likely to... I couldn't walk in 1984 so chasing may have been difficult but I can imagine "throwing"!

Comment: I scrubbed the comments related to this particular user, since we don't want to publicly shame anyone. The question stands by itself as a general one, and I wanted to focus discussion on that.

Comment: @BradLarson There's something strange with that user's rating. Despite having more than 40 positively rated answers (+many zero-rated accepted answers), only a few downvotes and NO offered bounties, his rating was 34 right before the temporary suspension. How could it happen?

Comment: @BradLarson And now after the ban he has >1K rating. What was that? Serial downvoting caused by the Meta effect, now reversed, or something else?

Comment: @BradLarson I mentioned in my original question above that there was something strange with this guys since he was under the impression that his answer was given from an account with several thousand scoring votes.

Comment: @Idolon - All I will say is that this particular user has been dealt with. I recommend not dwelling on them any further.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You [*flag* the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) (use *offensive*) and **move on**. Leave dealing with a user like this to the moderators and do not engage. Flagging is only visible to moderators, the user cannot see that you have done so, nor can other users.

Moderators *will* engage the user if there are multiple cases of comments with offensive flags on them, and can do so in a private and non-conflicting manner. If a user doesn't improve their behaviour, temporarily banning the user is an option.

Most of all, do **not** call out the user here on Meta! Moderators try and address the *behaviour*, not the user. Calling out the user here only brings in the vigilantes, and we really don't want that.

Comment: relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback

Comment: Would you mind explaining the "temporarily" part in "temporarily banning" a bit further ? IMHO, such a user could be having a bad day but repeated offenses demonstrate a tendency to troll rather than providing constructive answers. Why would we want that type of user on SO ? Is there something I'm missing ? Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @2Dee: It is rare for a user to *persist* in disruptive behaviour, and we believe in second chances. See [A Day in the Penalty Box](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). If the user continues to be disruptive, longer bans are possible.

Comment: `Flagging is only visible to moderators, the user cannot see that you have done so` What happens if the user is a moderator?

Comment: @marflar: Then that user can see the flag, as can *other* moderators. They are held by the [moderator agreement](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) however.

Comment: A variation on the theme.  I saw a one sentence fly-by answer to a question.  I commented: "True, but how does this answer the question?:   The answerer added a sentence that said "and this might cause the problem you are seeing."   I followed that up with another comment that said "could you please explain what the OP can do to fix this?" and the answerer commented "F**k you, Dale Wilson".   As soon as I saw this comment, I flagged it as offensive, but the answerer deleted the comment just as quickly. Has he found a way to beat the system by erasing his tracks?

Comment: @DaleWilson: no, certain keywords make comments insta-deletable with an offensive flag. You found one of those keywords. They didn't delete the comment, *your flag* did. I'd expect any of the [7 dirty words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_dirty_words) to be on that list.

Comment: Ahh.  I understand now.  Thanks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what about those comments in my regional language? It happened me today. How would SO moderators handle those issue?

Comment: In this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737364/hyperlinking-a-html-table-row-to-its-corresponding-sql-record#comment59152441_35737364) actually I tried to help him by questioning for more details. He's commented abusively and it's deleted. Which may not comes under the `7-words` category, since it's the regional language.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan the user deleted the comment themselves. If you'd flagged that comment as offensive, I'd have asked a fellow moderator familiar with the language and / or used machine translation to check if the user needs contacting about their behaviour. For cases like these, a custom comment flag explaining what the comment is saying would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Absolutely !