# How to deal with users who's comments are "attacking" based on reputation?

Tags: discussion, comments, offensive

Today, I answered a basic question regarding regexes on Javascript.

Here is the question:
[Convert String ">number<" Into "><a href="tel:number">number</a><"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278462/convert-string-number-into-a-href-telnumbernumber-a/27278740)

The OP was always nice, and since it didn't took any time to answer, I just answered it (didn't took my time to ask what the OP tried, I just saw a cool and easy exercise and tried it).

It was a **very nice** day on SO!...

...Until a user decided to ruin it with bashing comments.

He came around "bragging" (don't take that word literally) about his 9k of reputation points, bashing me for answering and bashing the OP for not providing any tries he did (I didn't asked too).

I don't have any evidence (for now, hopefully my PC at work has the comments cached) since he deleted all the comments he made and the ones I made with his name.

How can I deal with people who behave like this?

More importantly, and kinda outside the scope, what does the rules say about this kind of behavior from users?

---

I am aware of this question:
[Offensive comments - How to deal with these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274302/offensive-comments-how-to-deal-with-these)

I can't flag them since they don't exist anymore.
That question is about insults, this one is more about "personal" attacks based on reputation and based on the OP's question.
This isn't insults, but I admit that those comments really hurt and that he can simply delete them and they are gone forever.

Comment: "he deleted all the comments he made and the ones I made with his name." A user who is not a diamond-moderator cannot by themselves delete comments made by another user. It would take a bunch of flags by different users (and of specific types like "rude" or "spam") or the intervention from a diamond-moderator for your comments to be deleted by someone other than yourself.

Comment: Save a screen shot and include it into your question next time.

Comment: @Louis He could delete his own comments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He deleted them before I had the chance.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You don't know that, you suspect it.  You only know *that* they were deleted, not by whom.

Comment: @Servy I read that sentence I quoted as saying the *other user* deleted his/her own comments *and* those left by Ismael Miguel.

Comment: @Louis Ah, I didn't notice that part.  In that case, it's almost certainly a mod.

Comment: @Servy Probably. I can easily see a third party stumbling upon the dispute and flagging some of the comments.

Comment: @Louis It would take 6 offensive flags to delete the content.  Either that or words in the blacklist in the comments.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, I wrote "rude" for "rude or offensive". I did not remember the exact number of flags needed. I'd expect spam to be treated the same since we do this already for questions and answers, am I wrong?

Comment: @Louis I'm pretty sure it's 6 flags to delete the post, and yes, spam flags do do the same thing.  I just don't see that question getting that much traffic for that to happen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I won't reproduce the comments here, but you're right, those were completely out of line. The comments were all removed in response to flags, and the user responsible was warned about them.

In the future, if you encounter behavior like this, flag the comments and we'll clean them up. If they are particularly severe, or there is a pattern of this behavior, we will discuss it with the commenter privately or take more serious action.

Comment: Thank you for dealing with them. I wanted to keep those comments there as long as possible, to be able to come home, printscreen them and show them (with the username properly hidden, obviously). Regarding to my answers to such comments, did I handled him properly? Should I have said different things? Should I have flagged them right on the spot? Should I have said something different? (I tried to keep it cool, but we are humans and humans "pop".)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel If someone is posting highly inappropriate/abusive comments you shouldn't be responding *at all*.  You should be flagging the content immediately, and doing nothing else.

Comment: @Servy I will keep that in mind. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Since the comments are already gone there is nothing else to do.

Comment: Basically, what you are saying is that anyone can come here, treat you under garbage, delete the comments and it's gone forever?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No, it's not gone forever, but there's nothing else that needs to be done because the comments are already gone.  There is no longer any problem to solve, because it has already been resolved.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The person can probably get away with it only a small number of times before it gets the attention of a moderator.

Comment: That's not a real solution. There isn't a way to report the user or something?

Comment: @Mysticial How many is "small"? 100? 1000? 1? Until then, how many persons need to be bashed for such "authority"?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel There's no *need* to.  There is no problem left to solve.  The content is all gone.  There is nothing else left to be done.  You *could* report it, and all the mod would say is that the situation had already been resolved.

Comment: @Servy Hopefully, I still have the page cached on that computer. Would that help if I got a printscreen?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No, because the comments are already deleted.  There's just nothing else to do.  If the comments weren't deleted, you could flag them to get them deleted.  As I've told you many times, it's not that you can't report the issue, it's that *there is nothing for the mod to do* in response to the flag.  The content is already gone.  They're just going to see a flag telling them that there's a problem that has already been solved, and have nothing to do.